# How to parse gzipped data in NodeJS submitted by external api

Tags: javascript, node.js, gzip, zlib

An external API sends a POST request with its results compressed in the gzip format to my postback_url. Here is what I get in body param. Btw, I shorten the output as it is a very long string.

```
body: '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
```

How can I unzip them and convert them to JSON format? I tried with the code given https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html but failed with it.  I will highly appreciate some sample easy-to-understand code or any references.

Comment: The data is Base64 encoded. You need to first decode the Base64 to the original binary, and then gunzip it.

Comment: @MarkAdler  const buff = Buffer.from(event.body, 'base64');  have u meant something like that?

Comment: That should do it.

Comment: Is it possible to get a "working" body paylod? And not the shorted version?

Comment: Yes. Here it is https://anotepad.com/notes/c7ccprqc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a gzip in base64 then you can Decode it like this.

```
const zlib = require('zlib');

const buffer = Buffer.from(data, 'base64');

zlib.unzip(buffer, { finishFlush: zlib.constants.Z_SYNC_FLUSH }, (err, buffer) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('An error occurred:', err);
    }
    console.log(JSON.parse(buffer.toString()));
});
```

Comment: Tried. Output is like WH+P���y��h&H�K�
                  �?�;lX���R-��:h�u�o=7x�D�
�9�^ٵ�/����,S���Q�!V"z���5�DAV�7`{f�d���h47�����=P��L1��rm�n�X2~�<m&��|[���'�`�āy�e�Vvx�_١P8E�'��%

Comment: Then there is no text in base64. In which format does the external API return your data?

Comment: POST request with its results compressed in the gzip format

Comment: OK that's how it should be

Comment: Any hints to convert them to JSON output?

Comment: does it throw an error at JSON parse?

Comment: at Zlib.zlibOnError [as onerror] (node:zlib:191:17) {
  errno: -3,
  code: 'Z_DATA_ERROR'
}
undefined

Comment: what happens if you start with `zlib.constants.BROTLI_OPERATION_FLUSH`