# Z_DATA_ERROR while trying to decompress using zlib's unzip in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, zlib

I receive data as zipped from the server.  The body propery holds the following data:

```
 body: '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
```

In my local machine, I am trying with the following code:

```
const {  unzip } = require("zlib");
let data =
    "H4sIAAAAAAAAA+z92XLjyLI2Cr4KqupUprSSRBKch2LmpiRKouZ5KtWfhiFIQgQBCgAnKWX2X/T1uTndZn1xjtmx/66fYJv15e432U/S7hGYCUqURGWWan...." // the same data as received in body property 
let buffer = Buffer.from(data);
 
 
unzip(buffer, (err, buffer) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error("An error occurred:", err);
        process.exitCode = 1;
    }
    console.log(buffer);
});
```

Output:

```
  at Zlib.zlibOnError [as onerror] (node:zlib:191:17) {
  errno: -3,
  code: 'Z_DATA_ERROR'
}
undefined
```

I will highly appreciate your help. Where is the mistake or is there any better approach to get what I want to get?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse gzipped data in NodeJS submitted by external api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68650960/how-to-parse-gzipped-data-in-nodejs-submitted-by-external-api)

Comment: That looks like base64 encoded data… try decoding it first.

Comment: @Marc no. Thanks

Comment: Thats exaclty the same question, 1:1 with 2 diffrent titles.

Comment: Two different queries actually for two different options within the same problem. This question is to resolve a particular error.

Comment: The mistake is you did not decode the Base64 encoding. But you already know this from your other question.

Comment: The problem is solved. I did some mistakes with decoding. The solution is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68650960/how-to-parse-gzipped-data-in-nodejs-submitted-by-external-api